# Redimensionar imagen en CSS3

Tags: html, css3, imagen

Buenas a todos,

Estoy intentando poner una imagen de fondo por CSS3. En este caso, le pongo lo siguiente:

HTML

```
<div class="seccion_1" ></div>
```

CSS

```
.seccion_1 {
  background: url('desarrollo/equipo.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  left: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
```

La imagen la coloca en todo el ancho del navegador, pero solo coge un trozo de la imagen. Entiendo que si pongo background-size: cover; tendría que adaptarse la imagen a la caja.

¿Cómo se puede adaptar la imagen a la caja con otro metodo? ¿Pór que no se adapta la imagen?

La imagen tiene un tamaño de 1280X1024.

Gracias!

Editado: Un recorte de como quedaría.

[image: Imagen]

Comment: Sería un recorte de como queda la imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pues sencillo solo que haces como ya tienes, el estilo, no coloques el heigth con alto fijo, marcalo con porcentaje asi se adapta el largo de ventana

```
.seccion_1 {
  background: url('desarrollo/equipo.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  left: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
//yo haria los singuiente
.seccion_1 {
  background: url('desarrollo/equipo.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  left: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.seccion_1 {
  background: url('desarrollo/equipo.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Es por el left 25%; que te lo lanza a la izquierda y por eso queda el espacio.

Comment: Lo que ocurre que si le elimino el left, también desaparece el menú de la parte izquierda. Tengo repartido el 25% para el menú y el 75% para la caja que contiene la imagen.

Comment: ok entonces lo que tu quieres es que, la imagen se ajuste al alto? y al ancho tambien?

Comment: Eso es, la imagen al 100% del ancho (75%) y el alto que solo tenga 400px, pero dimensionando la imagen (que se vea al completo).

Comment: Ok mira te explico según mi conocimiento, la imagen no se va ver completa si no colocas la misma altura de la imagen, es por que tu tipo de imagen es formato .jpg, la mayoria de developers web trabajan con formatos de imagen .svg que permiten un responsive sin perder la mayoria parte de la imagen.

Comment: Entonces para solucionar el problema ¿debería convertir la imagen .jpg en svg?

Comment: Pues yo te recomendaría eso, trabajar con imágenes que sean banners en formatos svg, quizás alguien mas te puede dar otra respuesta..

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo  Pablnho.

Comment: Dale con gusto.

Comment: Hola, mira [answer] para ver como construir una buena respuesta. Fue reportada como de baja calidad, ya que solo tiene código y ninguna explicación, fíjate que tuviste que explicar todo en los comentarios. Por favor agrega todo eso a la respuesta.

Comment: ok gracias es que soy nuevo

Answer (score 0):

conozco un código css que le aplicas a cualquier imagen y hace que sea responsive para cualquier resolución que la quieras ver.

La imagen se adaptara al div al que corresponda, el código css es el siguiente:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto/9; /* Bug de ie8 */
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos.

Comment: Fedo, te sugiero revises [answer], saludos.

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. La pregunta es sobre imágenes de fondo (`background-image`) pero tu solución es para imágenes (con la etiqueta `img`).